# Dynamic creating an "OR" Query in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to create an AND queryset in django. The query is Give me all customers with certain id's. I have id's stored in a python list. My initial thought was the following

```
ids = range(1,21)
specific_customers = []
customers = Customer.objects.all() //Get them all
for customer in customers:
    if customer.pk in ids:
        specific_customers.append(customer)
```

but I don't think this is the preffered and best way to do it. Any better or faster ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
ids = range(1,21)
specific_customers = Customer.objects.filter(pk__in=ids)
```

---

Alternatively, if the use of `range()` is not just an example, and this really will always be a range of numbers you should use [`range` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) instead:

```
specific_customers = Customer.objects.filter(pk__range=(1, 21))
```

Both examples are equivalent to your original code.

Comment: dammnnn !!!!! Didn't know django had this thing!! Thank you Ludwik, saved my day!